# Canonical Partners

Tags: canonical

I do not find Canonical Partners in my software and updates in order to activate them to continue to install Skype as indicated in this forum. What can I do?
Regards

Answer (score 1):

The GUI way of adding the Canonical Partner repository can be found at https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/addremove-sources.html. The steps are:

1. Press <kbd>Super</kbd> to open the Dash and search for "Software & Updates"
2. Click on "Other Software" followed by the "Add..." button
3. In the "APT line: " box, enter `deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner`
4. Click on "Add Source"

Comment: Thank you very much. Easy. That is the beauty I’m discovering.